# How to limit the number of processes in python twisted server?

Tags: python, multithreading, server, process, twisted

Basically I need to implement non-threaded single process server using twisted
Some analogue of Flask's

> app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, **threaded=False**, **processes=1**)

Currently i'm using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    reactor_args = {}

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.web.server import Site
    from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource

    reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(1)
    resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)
    site = Site(resource)
    reactor.listenTCP(5000, site, backlog=1, interface='0.0.0.0')
    reactor.run(**reactor_args)
```

So what should be done additionally to achieve single process in twisted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already set thread pool size to 1.

Comment: Yep, but seems it's not enough as I am still getting some error that used to appear for multiprocessed flask

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error you're trying to fix.

Comment: The error is not related to Python part. But I am accessing some third party system that does not support multiprocess
I just want to understand if there are any other means to control number of processes in twisted

Comment: Some conclusion: as mentioned by szatkus, the thread number control is in place already. But other than that I've learnt here https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-15.1.0/web/howto/web-in-60/session-basics.html that SIte creates a new session and for my case that causes the problem.
So closing the issue as the question from the subj is answered